# Вставил несколько сниппетов в Emmet, но почему-то не срабатывает

Tags: sublime-text, emmet

Пользуюсь Sublime Text. В пользовательских настройках Еmmet вставил свои сниппеты:

```
{
    "snippets": {
        "html": {
            "abbreviations": {
                "jq:":"<script src=\"//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js\"></script>",  
                "sl:":"<script src=\"http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectivizr/1.0.2/selectivizr-min.js\"></script>",
                "pr:":"<script src=\"http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js\"></script>",
                "three:":"<script src=\"http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r50/three.min.js\"></script>"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

При нажатии <kbd>Tab</kbd> на стандартные тэги всё работает. Но после написания своего сниппета, например, <kbd>Tab</kbd> после jq делает просто табуляцию, а если нажимать <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>, то выведется `<jq></jq>`.

Почему не получается воспользоваться своими сниппетами, и как сделать, чтобы работало?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Snippets](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html)

Сниппеты в Sublime Text представляют собой обычный XML файл с расширением **"`.sublime-snippet`"**

Для того, чтобы создать новый сниппет, следует выполнить следующее: 
`Tools -> New Snippet`

`<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
    echo "<pre>"; var_dump(${1:var})${0}; echo "</pre>";
}]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>deb</tabTrigger>
    <scope>source.php</scope>
    <description>debug</description>
</snippet>`

и сохранить в ..\Packages\PHP\snippetName.sublime-snippet,

где

**`content`** - непосредственно содержание сниппета;

**`tabTrigger`** - название сниппета.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно поменять  "abbreviations" на "snippets"и все заработает. Снипеты от емета круче чем встроенные т.к. их можно умножать и прочие плюшки от емета работают.

```
{
"snippets": {
    "html": {
        "snippets": {
            "jq:":"<script src=\"//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js\"></script>",  
            "sl:":"<script src=\"http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectivizr/1.0.2/selectivizr-min.js\"></script>",
            "pr:":"<script src=\"http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js\"></script>",
            "three:":"<script src=\"http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r50/three.min.js\"></script>"
        }
    }
}
```

}